# Converting binary number to decimal useing string

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I've tried to write a simple function, which input is binary number in string format and converts binary to decimal. But in the output I always get the wrong thing: the 'res' value in line 3, no matter what the input is ('1010', '10010111010', etc.). Also, I've tried to debug the code and the function doesn't even start the loop, as if it wasn't there... So, I just don't see my mistake

```
def bin_to_dec(bin):

    bin = bin[::-1]
    res = 0

    for i in range(len(bin)):
        if bin[i] == 0:
            res += 2**i

    return res
```

Comment: @Laif Why do you say that?

Comment: You added some stuff while I wrote my comment. Clearly he OP is doing base arithmetic so exponentiation is almost certainly what they want and need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the string `"0"` to the number 0 and they are, trivially, unequal.

So, contrary to what you say, the loop is actually looping; but the `if` statement will never be true.

Of course, also, you should probably add when the number is 1, not when it's 0.

```py
def bin_to_dec(bin):
    bin = bin[::-1]
    res = 0
    for i in range(len(bin)):
        if int(bin[i]) == 1:
            res += 2**i
    return res
```

Notice the addition of `int()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if bin[i] == '1'
```

This will correct the problem. `bin[i]` is a character and you are comparing it to a number which always results in false.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the built in int function:

```
def binaryToDecimal(n): 
    return int(n,2)
```